# Very fast brass oxidation

Tags: metal, metallurgy, surface-chemistry, alloy

I work for a company that manufactures pyrotechnics for the oil and gas industry, and we have been having an odd phenomenon occur.

One part, a brass tube with a copper clip filled with black powder, is placed into a steel receptacle. Another part, consisting of a blend of black powder, asphalt, epoxy, and a little ammonium nitrate (and possibly a few other materials) in a steel tube is placed into the same atmospheric chamber, but does not come in physical contact with the first part. The chamber is sealed up, and the brass tube is covered in blue corrosion within minutes. I don't think that the second part is offgasing, because it's in a sealed package prior to use which never builds up any pressure. What could be causing it to corrode so fast? I think the customers are using a caustic cleaner in the tool which isn't being fully removed that's reacting with the brass, but they seem to think it's an interaction between the two tools. Any thoughts?